# Grails Property Expression instead of Domain Object in Web Flow?

Tags: grails, properties, expression, spring-webflow

We are currently trying to build some stuff with Grails Web Flows.

We are setting an object in the Flow (using flow.objectName = objectInstance), but when we try to access it in the next step of the Flow (using flow.objectName), the Object is not set, but instead there is a org.codehaus.groovy..... .PropertyExpression, that has none of the methods we want to use.

The Code we used to set and get works in other cases, and we cannot find any differences.

- What is a Property Expression?
- What are we doing wrong, any clues or Problems that happen often with Webflows?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: An example would be helpful since most grails webflow issues are dsl syntax related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Webflow DSL syntax is correct.

For example

```
def someFlow = {
    eventAction {
       flow.value = someValue // This is incorrect
       action {
           flow.value = someValue // This is correct
       }
       on("success").to "eventDisplay"
    }

    eventDisplay {
       on("finish").to "end"
       flow.anotherValue = somethingElse // This usually causes the behavior you are seeing.
       // Proper way of setting flow.anotherValue
       on("finish2") {
           flow.anotherValue = somethingElse
       }.to "end"

    }

    end{}
}
```